# Shell Talend variables

Tags: shell, talend

I am trying to set environmental variables in shell script to be used by a talend job. 
I have used export command. The Talend job that uses the script throws a null exception.

**EDIT from comment**

```
export DATE=date +%Y%m%d 
./job1.sh
```

But I receive the below error:

```
Processing Date : null Exception in component tMysqlInput_2 (job1) 
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null at 
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542) at 
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
```

Comment: Show us the code you already tried, and the full details of the exception that was received.  There isn't enough information here to know what question you would like answered.

Comment: Would you please add your script here ? So people could help you resolve your issue. Thanks.

Comment: export DATE=`date +%Y%m%d`
./job1.sh
but i receive the below error:
Processing Date : null
Exception in component tMysqlInput_2 (job1)
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)

Comment: Then you have an error in your job, not in the export function.

Comment: the talend job works on talend studio, as windows batch script. But not able to run the job in linux server. after rectifying the variable name i now receive the below output:Processing Date : 28082017 Exception in component tMysqlInput_2 (job1) 
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null at 
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542) at 
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to use the DATE variable as a context variable in your job. First you need to declare the corresponding variable in your job's context parameters (say it's called date). Then you need to read the DATE variable in your job1.sh script, and pass its value along to your job as a context parameter :

```
java -Xms64M -Xmx1024M job.full.name --context_parameter date="$(echo $DATE)"
```